# Reading a file in Nodejs displays 0 Bytes

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

When I try to read a file in Nodejs it displays 0 bytes.

The code:

```
fs.readFile("thisArticle.html", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
if (err) {
return console.log(err);
}


console.log(data.byteLength); // Displays 0 bytes




});
```

Also when I try this way, the same issue it displays 0 bytes.

```
var stats = fs.statSync("thisArticle.html", 'utf8');
var fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
var fileSizeInMegabytes = fileSizeInBytes / 1000000.0;

console.log(fileSizeInMegabytes); // Displays 0 bytes
```

I would like to know if I am missing something because path of file is correct and I don't know if it's something with code itself or HTML files especially

Comment: Wild guess... the file is actually empty?

Comment: Try using the complete address of the file, including the domain that it is served from.

Comment: In your first code snippet, console.log is in the if statement...  In the second one, what does the "stats" variable value displays you?

Comment: Moreover data.byteLenth does not exists, that's data.length... byteLength is a static method of Buffer (https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding)

Comment: @maxx-t yes I've updated the code, now is not under if statement that I missed during the copy paste here. Anyway as per second the stats displays this on console:

{ dev: -1170857284,
  mode: 33206,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 0,
  gid: 0,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: undefined,
  ino: 281474977110397,
  size: 0,
  blocks: undefined,
  atime: 2017-08-24T15:19:43.626Z,
  mtime: 2017-08-29T22:55:12.939Z,
  ctime: 2017-08-29T22:55:12.939Z,
  birthtime: 2017-08-24T15:19:43.626Z }

Comment: @kpie The file is in a local folder under the project, why do you mean by complete address?

Comment: @Tomalak Is not because I am writing it via createWriteStream and I can see it locally that the file is created and have the content inside.

Comment: Add ./ to the beginning of the file name if it is in the same folder as the script.

Comment: If you are working under windows, it may be a known bug: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12737; otherwise try `"blksize: undefined" "size: 0"` with google

Answer (score 0):

Try this code you will get the html file in console

```
var fs= require('fs');
fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, data){
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log('test file is loaded:\n',data.toString());
});
```

Comment: You need to keep your html file in the place of ./index.html check this is printing html code in terminal